# MongoDB Spark Connector - aggregation is slow

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I am running the same aggregation pipeline with a Spark Application and on the Mongos console. On the console, the data is fetched within the blink of an eye, and only a second use of "it" is needed to retrieve all expected data. 
The Spark Application however takes almost two minutes according to the Spark WebUI.

[image]

As you can see, 242 tasks are being launched to fetch the result. I am not sure why such an high amount of tasks is launched while there are only 40 documents being returned by the MongoDB aggregation. It looks like there is a high overhead.

The query I run on the Mongos console:

```
db.data.aggregate([
   {
      $match:{
         signals:{
            $elemMatch:{
               signal:"SomeSignal",
               value:{
                  $gt:0,
                  $lte:100
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $group:{
         _id:"$root_document",
         firstTimestamp:{
            $min:"$ts"
         },
         lastTimestamp:{
            $max:"$ts"
         },
         count:{
            $sum:1
         }
      }
   }
])
```

The Spark Application code

```
    JavaMongoRDD<Document> rdd = MongoSpark.load(sc);

    JavaMongoRDD<Document> aggregatedRdd = rdd.withPipeline(Arrays.asList(
            Document.parse(
                    "{ $match: { signals: { $elemMatch: { signal: \"SomeSignal\", value: { $gt: 0, $lte: 100 } } } } }"),
            Document.parse(
                    "{ $group : { _id : \"$root_document\", firstTimestamp: { $min: \"$ts\"}, lastTimestamp: { $max: \"$ts\"} , count: { $sum: 1 } } }")));

    JavaRDD<String> outputRdd = aggregatedRdd.map(new Function<Document, String>() {
        @Override
        public String call(Document arg0) throws Exception {
            String output = String.format("%s;%s;%s;%s", arg0.get("_id").toString(),
                    arg0.get("firstTimestamp").toString(), arg0.get("lastTimestamp").toString(),
                    arg0.get("count").toString());
            return output;
        }
    });

    outputRdd.saveAsTextFile("/user/spark/output");
```

After that, I use `hdfs dfs -getmerge /user/spark/output/ output.csv` and compare the results.

Why is the aggregation so slow? Isn't the call to `withPipeline` meant to reduce the amount of data needed to be transfered to Spark? It looks like it isn't doing the same aggregation the Mongos console does. On the Mongos console it is blazing fast. I am using Spark 1.6.1 and mongo-spark-connector_2.10 version 1.1.0.

Edit: Another thing I am wondering about is that two executors get launched (because I am using the default execution settings atm), but only one executor does all the work. Why isn't the second executor doing any work?

[image]

Edit 2: When using a different aggregation pipeline and calling `.count()` instead of `saveAsTextFile(..)`, there are also 242 tasks being created. This time there will be 65.000 documents returned. 
[image]

Comment: I'd look into the UI more to try and understand what the 242 tasks are.  With 40 documents I'd imagine it would all fit in a single partition.

Comment: @Ross 242 tasks also get created when i run a different query and `.count()` on `aggregatedRdd` instead of saving it to hdfs. The different query returns a few million documents. My collection stats are: `data : 15.01GiB docs : 45141000 chunks : 443`. I doubt writing it to the HDFS is the problem. It's just the only action that gets called in my spark application that's why it's listed as the only stage in the web UI. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Ross I somehow feel like the aggregation pipeline is not executed. Do I have to specifically execute the aggregation pipeline?

Comment: @Ross I just ran another aggregation with just this as the pipeline: `Document.parse("{ $match: {ts: {$gt: ISODate(\"2016-02-22T08:30:26.000Z\"), $lte: ISODate(\"2016-02-22T08:44:35.000Z\")} } }")` and again 242 tasks get created when I call `.count()` on the rdd. Any idea what's wrong? I have added another image to the original post.

Comment: I expect the result of `count()` to be the correct, meaning the aggregation is passed down to MongoDB correctly.  I think the issue is going to be picking a better partitioner for this workload: If you call  `outputRdd.partitions.size` what is the value? 242?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127393/discussion-between-ross-and-j9dy).

Comment: @Ross I came back from vacation and have added comments in the chat. Thanks for trying to help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The high number of tasks is caused by the default Mongo Spark partitioner strategy. It ignores the aggregation pipeline when calculating the partitions,  for two main reasons:

1. It reduces the cost of calculating partitions
2. Ensures the same behaviour for sharded and non-sharded partitioners

However, as you've found they can generate empty partitions which in your case is costly.

The choices for fixing could be:

1. Change partitioning strategy

   For choose an alternative partitioner to reduce the number of partitions.  For example the PaginateByCount will split the database into a set number of partitions.

   Create your own partitioner - simply implement the trait and you will be able to apply the aggregation pipeline and partition up the results.  See the [HalfwayPartitioner](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark/blob/r2.0.0/src/test/scala/com/mongodb/spark/HalfwayPartitioner.scala) and [custom partitioner test](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark/blob/r2.0.0/src/test/scala/com/mongodb/spark/MongoRDDSpec.scala#L128-L138) for an example.
2. Pre aggregate the results into a collection using $out and read from there.
3. Use `coalesce(N)` to coalesce the partitions together and reduce the number of partitions.
4. Increase the `spark.mongodb.input.partitionerOptions.partitionSizeMB` configuration to produce fewer partitions.

A custom partitioner should produce the best solution but there are ways to make better use of the available default partitioners.

If you think there should be a default partitioner that uses the aggregation pipeline to calculate the partitions then please add a ticket to the MongoDB [Spark Jira project](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SPARK).

Comment: Can I use the `MongoShardedPartitioner` for a collection with hashed sharding? The documentation says `shardkey - The field should be indexed and contain unique values.` In my case, I have a combined sharding key out of my fields `log_file_name:day_of_timestamp:hour_of_timestamp` which results to saving relevant data close together - at least I hope it does so. But the values pre-hashing are not unique. Is the documentation talking about the hashed value? Also I had a small follow up question on how to use MongoSpark for multiple queries in the chat  -- if you mind taking a look at it.